# How to show a div if input is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I did this code to show a div when people select one input radio, but doesn't work. 
Unfortunately the input is inside a .tpl page (PrestaShop) and it's a group. So I did it calling the value 23. If I put some css it works, but when I set "show" the div stays hide. What is wrong?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#group_1 input').each(function () {
      if ($(this).val() == ('23') && $(this).is(':checked')) {
              $('#showtext').show();

      } else {
          $('#showtext').hide();
      }
  });
  });



 {elseif $group.group_type == 'radio'}
    <ul id="group_{$id_attribute_group}">
      {foreach from=$group.attributes key=id_attribute item=group_attribute}
        <li class="input-container float-xs-left">
          <label class="accordion--form__label">
            <input class="input-radio" type="radio" data-product-attribute="{$id_attribute_group}" name="group[{$id_attribute_group}]" value="{$id_attribute}"{if $group_attribute.selected} checked="checked"{/if}>
            <span class="radio-label">{$group_attribute.name}</span>
          </label>
        </li>
      {/foreach}
    </ul>
  {/if}
```

Comment: What's that templating engine you're using?

Comment: `{elseif $group.group_type == 'radio'}` looks problematic given the tags on the question.

Comment: @RobG what do you suggest? Because that it's PrestaShop code, I can't edit it. 

JackBashford it's smarty

Comment: You have jQuery and javascript tags, but that isn't javascript. If it's Smarty or PrestaShop or some other language, you should add a tag for it.

Comment: I see...but I don't know how to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#group_1 input').each(function() {
                if ($(this).val() == ('23') && $(this).is(':checked')) {
                    $('#showtext').show();
    
                } else {
                    $('#showtext').hide();
                }
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "group_1" >

        <input class = "input-radio"  type = "radio" data-product-attribute = "data-product-attribute" name = "test" value = "23" checked>
        </div>
        
        <div id = "showtext" >Show text </div>
```

You can see code above is working absolutely fine. You have applied display:none !important;to showtext in your css code.

Comment: To me it doesn't work. The div showtext doesn't show when I check the input